# How to match and replace an attribute value inside a tag

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to replace the value of following node using sed command.

```
<KeyValue key="EMPTY_SEARCH_CRITERIA" type="String" value="CS_CODE" comment="Configured empty search criteria."/>
```

I am using wildcard since initial value could contain any string value. For eg.

```
sed -e 's/value=.*/value="SN_CODE,CS_ID" comment="Configured empty search criteria."\/\>/g' CMS_conf.xml > tempfile
         ^        ^                                                                     ^
```

But then, in this case, I have to include the comment attribute too.

Is there any way I can accomplish this without entering comment attribute?

Comment: [Required reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5419599)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the perl dialect of regular expressions. If you are on a system with `sed`, then you're likely to have perl.

## Given

```
<KeyValue key="EMPTY_SEARCH_CRITERIA" type="String" value="CS_CODE" comment="Configured empty search criteria."/>
```

## Perl Regex

```
perl -i -pe 's/(value=)".*?"/\1"some_replacement_string"/g' <filename>
```

## Notes

You may want to test this first  by first printing to terminal.

```
perl -pe 's/(value=)".*?"/\1"some_replacement_string"/g' <filename>
```

Or create a backup with extension `.bak`

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/(value=)".*?"/\1"some_replacement_string"/g' <filename>
```

Regular Expression Explained:

- (): group as variable \1
- ": quotations are literal because of the single quoted expression, so no need to escape them.
- ?: serves to tame *, meaning it will stop gobbling at the first match (and not keep munching until the final ". `sed` does not support non-greedy operators, but you can use the trick in the other answer `[^"]*"`, which means gobble all characters up that are not " up until a ". This effectively does the same thing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is not the brightest choice for html (or any other programming language) processing, but anyhow:

```
sed -e 's/\(value\)="[^"]*"/\1="SN_CODE,CS_ID"/'
```

Two perhaps not obvious points:

- with `\(` and `\)` we group a pattern to use it later on with `\1`
- `[^"]*` is used to match any char but a `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you particularly want change the CS_CODE with SN_CODE,CS_ID you can use:

```
's/CS_CODE/SN_CODE,CS_ID/g'
```

If the values differ you can use

```
's/value=\S*\S/value="SN_CODE,CS_ID"/g'
```